# Swagger Spec Validation in Java

Tags: java, validation, swagger

iam trying to validate some strings that may contain swagger specifications. Iam trying to use the swagger parser.

The following code doesn't work. I only get the message: "[attribute  is not of type `object`]"

The swagger spec is read out of an xml file.

```
swaggerXml = nodeList.item(0).getTextContent();
            SwaggerDeserializationResult res = new SwaggerParser().readWithInfo(swaggerXml);
            for (int i = 0; i < res.getMessages().size(); i++){
                log.info(res.getMessages().toString());
            }
```

Is this method wrong? Or. what is the meaning of the error message?
I just want to know if the string contains a valid Swagger specification in JSON format.

Thanks for your help.

---

Update: Problem solved

As far as I could see the error is thrown if the string is not json valid. First I check if the json is valid and only then execute the swagger parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just want to provide my solution i figured out a while ago.

```
SwaggerParser parser = new SwaggerParser();
SwaggerDeserializationResult result = parser.readWithInfo(swaggerXml);
List<String> messageList = result.getMessages();
```

And then print the list elements.